# Angularjs complete all promise before destroying the page

Tags: angularjs, promise

I am trying to build an AngularJS single page application with Java Spring as rest service.

Currently my controller allows me to save all the filled data to the back end which I have something like this in my code:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    personalDataService.saveData.query({}, {
        personalData: $scope.personalData
    }, function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

In another page, I loaded the part of the data from the same table in order to do some validation, for example checking if user is female to determine she needs to fill another form.

The problem is while I am leaving this page, the promise for save is not return yet, the second page has been loaded and the data is not completed. If I refresh the second page again then everything is back to normal

Is there any way to make sure all the promise has been return before destroy/ leaving this page?

Comment: You can use interceptors to keep a track of all promises. And depending on the status of the promise you can enable or disable the link to second page.

Comment: If the data has to span sessions, then use cookie or localStorage, both of which are addressed synchronously. Otherwise, keep the data in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Once the promise is resolved, emit a event.

```
function saveFields() {

     var deferred = $q.defer();

  // in your save fields function, resolve the promise on success save or reject the promise on error.

      onSaveCall(args, onSuccess, onFail);

      var onSucess = function() {deferred.resolve()};

     return deferred.promise;
 }

 $scope.$on('destroy', function () {
     onSaveCall.then(function () {
       // Here your save fields is resolved then write your code to emit or notify.
    })
 })
```

If you have more than one promise use promises.all https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score -1):

Build an array of all your promises running (for example, by storing them in a `service`, in the `$rootScope` or via `events`) and wait for the completion by using [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
   $q.all($rootScope.promises).then(function(){
       console.log('all promises finished');

   });
}
```